# Auto remove Mysqli row when date is equal to current date but above 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime, mysqli

On my CMS, the user is able to select a date on the post on which it will expire, currently this works fine and the post does automatically expire when the date chosen is equal to the current date.

I would like to make it that if the user does not enter a date then the post will never expire, currently the default value for the date field in the database when the user leaves the field on the CMS blank is 0000-00-00, I want my expire code to basically skip this date and leave any records which have this date associated to them.

Here is my expire data code :

```
$SQL = $conn->query("

DELETE FROM data 
WHERE expire <= CURDATE()

");
```

I have attempted to change it however this does not work

```
$SQL = $conn->query("

DELETE FROM data 
WHERE expire <= CURDATE() && < '0000-00-00'");
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: You could store the value as `NULL` instead of `0000-00-00` when left blank. Then you could just use the first query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `AND` and not `&&` and then just specify that the `expire` should not be `'0000-00-00'`

```
DELETE FROM data 
WHERE expire <= CURDATE() 
  AND expire != '0000-00-00'
```

> WARNING: modern versions of MYSQL do not like the default date being set to '0000-00-00' [See the Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-types.html)

Comment: You say, MYSQL does not like 0000-00-00 is there a way to store the date value in a better way when the field is left blank ?

Comment: Its basically a change made to MYSQL 5.7, you will need to check that manual link I posted. It was more for future reference if you are not using MYSQL5.7 yet

Comment: @BradleyCousins you can always make the column NULLable and set default to NULL

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE date <= CURDATE() AND date != '0000-00-00'";
```